# Tranform geometry to WGS 84

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2, wgs84

I need to transform some line and polygon geometry to WGS 84.

[image]

At point it working fine, but at the line and polygone I have problems, I tried in many ways, but it does not work.
In the screenshot you can see the geom Coordinates. How can I transform to WGS 84?

Comment: What projection are your data in now? Have you tried reprojecting in open source software like QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you can add your code will be better to understand.. However, this function helps you to convert your geometry to WGS-84

```
var ProjLayer = new ol.Layer.Vector("vector", {
           projection: map.displayProjection,
           preFeatureInsert: function(feature) {
           feature.geometry.transform([yourprojection],projWGS84);   //change here to your data projection
           }
        });
```